# PHPUnit + PHPStorm: Different errors for run/debug

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm

I am starting with unit-testing for my project, but run into difficulties. I have one test that runs perfectly when I run it alone. When I run the whole lot of tests I have, it fails: (*I have removed other code and specific class/variable/function names on purpose*)

```
class XYZTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function setUp() {
        $xml = $this->createXML();
        //...
    }


    public function testWillFailUponRunAllTests() {
        $this->subject = new XYZ();
        $result = $this->subject->getHelpText();
        //assert this and that
    }
}
```

**Execute single test**: Runs perfectly.

**Execute all tests**: I get an error of a class that I have injected. This is strange, so I'd like to debug the test to see what is going on.

**Debug all tests**: I don't even get to the error, because `setUp()` already causes this error message: `XYZTest::setUp(): Invalid State Error`

Obviously, this happens neither when I run the test isolated, nor when I run all tests in "normal" mode. Only in debug mode!

**Debug single test**: I get yet another behaviour:
`PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult::run(): Invalid State Error' in phar://C:/xampp/php/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestResult.php on line 668`. This happens only when I set breakpoints, not when I disable them, for example. Seems a PHPStorm bug.

I am using PHP 5.5.9, PHPStorm 7.1.3, PHPUnit 3.7.31, xDebug v2.2.3. I'm not using any PHP framework. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe you have followed the tutorials on PHPUnit correctly. The setUp() function is run before each test, as each test is run in isolation.  Therefore, you need to write your tests for that.

```
class XYZTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    protected $xml;     // Internal Object for testing

    // Assume you have autoloader configured in bootstrap. If not, Require your class to test
    //require_once('YourXMLClass.php');
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->xml = new YourXMLClass();        // Create the XML object so it exists for testing.
    }

    public function testXMLIsEmpty()
    {
        $this->assertNull($this->xml->subject);
    }

    public function testXMLSubjectSet()
    {
        $this->xml->SetSubject('Basic Text to be returned as XML subject field');
        $this->assertEquals('<subject>Basic Text to be returned as XML subject field</subject>', $this->xml->subject);
    }
}
```

The assumption in my test is you have a SetSubject method in your class that adds the parameter to the subject field of your XML.  IE:

```
public function SetSubject($SubjectText)
{
    $this->subject = '<subject>' . $SubjectText . '</subject>';
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that setUp() is executed before each test, thank you! My test looks exactly like your simulation. The problem is that I get an error but can't debug - wherever line of `XYZTest` I put a break in PHPStorm, the next Step into/Step over will throw that "Invalid State Error" and abort debugging. Running `XYZTest` on itself still passes without any error. I'll update my question.

Comment: Steven, I found the error and it is with PHPStorm's bootstrap file, which seems to have some inconsistencies. Also, either PHPStorm or PHPUnit seems to start behaving really weird sometimes when PHP throws errors, I encountered this before. This is probably best resolved with the devs, but thanks for hinting me in the right direction.

Comment: @PeerBr That is interesting with the error. I have been able to debug in the past with NetBeans, and PHPStorm, but have not tried it recently and not with the version you list.  Aside from setUp(), there is a matching tearDown(), and setUpBeforeClass()/tearDownAfterClasS() from section 6 of the PHPUnit documentation.